# What causes the rigid rod pendulum to spin about its centre of mass?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, rigid-body-dynamics

Please see diagram below showing a rigid rod mass 'm' connected at one end to a fixed frictionless pivot.

The rod swings from position A to B changing its orientation around its centre of mass.

Can anyone advise how an external torque can be formed that causes the rod to spin about its centre of mass?

[image]

Comment: The force from the pivot is not necessarily directed along the line of the rod.

Comment: I don't think that the rod is rotating about the center of mass. the center of mass is moving a circular path about the joint  due to the $~m\,g~$

Comment: The rod has changed it's orientation in space , therefore it has some spin about its COM. Why should the contact force with the pivot not be directed along the line of the rod through its COM?